# How well does WPA2 support work on an RaLink RT2760?

Tags: 10.04, server, wpa2

I found an old post saying that [WPA2 is not supported by the RTxxx (Ralink) drivers](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=318539).

- Is this statement still accurate for 10.04 LTS server?
- Is ndiswrapper being used automatically instead?

Case specific info:

I'm attempting to use a RaLink RT2760. This card auto-configured beautifully under Ubuntu 11.04, but I have a need for 10.04 LTS server, so I'm re-imaging.

```
$ iwconfig
wlan0 RT2860 Wireless  ESSID:""  Nickname:"RT2860STA"
      Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
      Bit Rate: 1 Mb/s
      RTS thr:off    Fragment thr:off
      Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:0 dBm  Noise level:-87 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc: 0  Missed beacon:0
```

makes it appear that everything is working properly, yet

```
$ iwlist scan
wlan0    No scan results
```

There are 8 discoverable networks in range.

Answer (score 2):

A few of suggestions:

*suggestion 1*

Try installing the wireless backports package to see if this resolves your issue.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-lucid-generic
```

*suggestion 2*

Possibly (though probably unlikely) this is a firmware issue and you need the non-free firmware package from the multiverse repo

enable the multiverse repo is `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

*suggestion 3*

10.04 now ships as an optional repository install, the 2.6.38 kernel that is used in 11.04 as well.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-backport-natty linux-headers-generic-lts-backport-natty
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know for that particular chipset or that particular release, but my Ralink 3062 definitely supports WPA2 on Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10. I had to download my driver directly from Ralink, though (rt2860 / rt3562sta).

To see the driver that is actually in use, run `sudo lspci -v`.